# dependsOn to instruct sbt to package dependent projects in multi-project build?

Tags: sbt

I created a multi-project build in sbt. Here's **build.sbt** in the main directory:

```
lazy val root = project in file(".") aggregate(data, reco, result)

lazy val data = project dependsOn(common)

lazy val reco = project 

lazy val result = project dependsOn(common)

lazy val common = project
```

When I use `package` or `one-jar` command, the classes and resources in `common` project are not packaged into `data` or `result` jars. So when I run the generated jar by

```
java -jar data_2.10-1.0-onejar.jar
```

it leads to NoClassDefFoundError as a consequence.

So could anyone help me deal with such problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It'd be worthwhile to explain *"leading to NoClassDefFoundError as a consequence"*, i.e. when exactly do you face the error? What command/task do you execute to end up with the error? Update your question, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding your issue...please pardon me if I have.

From [Classpath dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html#classpath-dependencies):

> A project may depend on code in another project. This is done by
>   adding a dependsOn method call.

and later (in the same doc):

> Now code in core can use classes from util. This also creates an
>   ordering between the projects when compiling them; util must be
>   updated and compiled before core can be compiled.

and then in [Per-configuration classpath dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html#per-configuration-classpath-dependencies):

> foo dependsOn(bar) means that the compile configuration in foo depends
>   on the compile configuration in bar.

We may also need to see what `package` is all about:

```
> help package
Produces the main artifact, such as a binary jar.  This is typically an alias for the task that actually does the packaging.
```

or even `inspect` it to see what dependencies it has:

```
> inspect package
[info] Task: java.io.File
[info] Description:
[info]  Produces the main artifact, such as a binary jar.  This is typically an alias for the task that actually does the packaging.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/C:/dev/sandbox/0.13.2/}root-0-13-2/compile:package
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Defaults) Defaults.scala:565
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  compile:packageBin
[info] Delegates:
[info]  compile:package
[info]  *:package
[info]  {.}/compile:package
[info]  {.}/*:package
[info]  */compile:package
[info]  */*:package
[info] Related:
[info]  jacoco:package
[info]  test:package
```

With all that said, `package` doesn't package other project's artifacts - you need the [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin instead (as you're crossing the boundaries of a single project and most if not all tasks in sbt are single-project only).

Comment: sbt-assembly can package the depended project? I found that sbt-onejar cannot perform such thing. When I package the jar by `one-jar` command, it only packages libraryDependancies but not the related project.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22556499/what-are-key-differences-between-sbt-pack-and-sbt-assembly

Answer (score 3):

Your dependent projects are not exporting Jars (producing classes only). Put the following line in the build.sbt of all dependent projects (including your current project too, if necessary):

```
exportJars := true
```

That should fix it.

Comment: I'm curious how would this actually produce the desired result? It this worked, it seems we would not need to use sbt-assembly in some cases.