# How to run jar generated by package (possibly with other jars under lib)?

Tags: scala, sbt

How can I run `.jar` file which is generated by sbt's `package`?

I created a really simple example with a single `.scala` source:

```
package org.pack {
    class ScalaParser(files: Array[String]) {
        def doAll() = {
            println("hello")
        }
    }

    object Main {
        def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
            val sp = new ScalaParser(args)
            sp.doAll()
        }

    }
}
```

After running

```
$ sbt
> compile
> package
```

`.jar` is created in `/target/scala-<version>`. If I try to run it, it fails giving this error:

```
$ java -jar package_2.9.2-0.1.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/ScalaObject
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.pack.Main.main(Main.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.ScalaObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 13 more
```

Note that no external libraries are used and `sbt compile run` works fine.

I attached [the whole project including generated .jar on dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0b663mewxt83c85/AAAsRl1DoThtzEcZlxOCi7Vca/package.zip).

What is really weird is the fact that `.jar` Manifest contains right class to load, i.e. `org.pack.Main`. Maybe it is caused by something else.

**System info**

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.9.2 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL
```

**Additional question** - what if I had some external `.jar`s in `/lib`? How can I assure that they are packed? I need one `.jar` runnable on (possibly) every JVM.

Thanks for help.

Comment: You should really look into the already-available answers in the sbt tag: see Outside sbt in [tag:sbt] and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22556499/what-are-key-differences-between-sbt-pack-and-sbt-assembly.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the *sbt* plugin [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly):

### sbt-assembly >= 0.12.0 with sbt >= 0.13.6

Since *sbt-assembly* is now an *auto plugin*, it is sufficient to add *project/assembly.sbt* to your *sbt* project:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.5")
```

### sbt-assembly 0.11

Add *project/assembly.sbt* to your *sbt* project:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.11.2")
```

Add *assembly.sbt* as well:

```
import AssemblyKeys._ // put this at the top of the file

assemblySettings
```

### Usage

This gives you another *sbt* command:

```
sbt assembly
```

which produces a "fat jar" (which includes all dependencies, including the Scala libraries).

Now you can start your program

> java -cp .../package-assembly.jar

so you only need a Java installation and the "fat jar".

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much, it works increadibly simply and well. I attach github link to stb-assembly for future readers https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

Comment: @petrbel You may also like http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Community-Plugins.html.

Comment: Note that sbt-assembly is now an auto plugin and the way you configure it in sbt has changed since the above answer was written. For the latest settings, see: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly And for migrating from old versions, see: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/blob/master/Migration.md

Comment: @Brideau Thanks for your hint; I have revised the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 16):

For those who do not wish to build a fat jar, all dependencies will have been downloaded as part of a successful run of `sbt package`. Classpath information is stored in a file within the `target` directory, which can be passed into the `java` command.

Example:

```
sbt package
java -cp target/scala-2.11/yourproject.jar:$(cat target/streams/compile/dependencyClasspath/\$global/streams/export) Main
```

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
scala package_2.9.2-0.1.jar
```

**Update**

From Java the command would look like this,

```
java -cp $SCALA_HOME/lib/scala-library.jar -jar  package_2.9.2-0.1.jar
```

Yet in the classpath you may need to add additional jar's, for instance `-cp "jar1.jar:jar2.jar"`

Comment: Yes, of course, this works fine, but how can I run it on regular JVM without scala installed? I assumed that it is possible as java/scala .class files are the same but compiler info etc. Or are they not? Is it even possible?

Comment: well you can place the scala jars in the /lib folder and when you will generate the fat jar it should package the scala libraries along with it and then you can run it where ever you want without needing to install scala

Comment: In case you need to mention the logger and main configuration files: java -Dlogback.configurationFile=dev-logger.xml -Dfile.ending=UTF8  -cp $SCALA_HOME/lib/scala-library.jar  -jar package_2.9.2-0.1.jar -Dconfig.file=application.conf