# scala akka websocket pack and run with scala command

Tags: scala, akka

I found [scala websocket](https://github.com/ScalaConsultants/websocket-akka-http) example on github

I cloned this repo and made some small changes, I could get the server up running with `sbt run` command.

I packed this into a `jar` file with `sbt package` command, and tried to run with `scala -classpath jarfilespath server.jar` command, but with no luch

I tried adding all dependencies in the `-classpath`, but I still got error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:com.typesafe.config.Config.getDuration`

I also tried using `sbt-assembly` plugin, which generated a 20M+ jar file, but still it's giving the same error message

How do I pack this into a jar file and run with `scala` command? thanks!

Comment: You can have a look at https://github.com/geoHeil/akkaStreamsIngest, in general `sbt package`or `assembly` should be fine. Maybe you are excluding some dependencies in the assembly configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the result of `sbt package` will not work for you as this creates a jar with just the code from this project, not its dependencies.

You are correct that one solution would be to use the [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin by adding to `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.4")
```

After this you can start the server with:

```
java -jar target/scala-2.11/websocket-akka-http-assembly-1.0.jar
```

Are you sure this gives you an error message? Which one exactly?

Comment: thank you for your update, I found answer from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24238060/how-to-run-jar-generated-by-package-possibly-with-other-jars-under-lib), it works for me