# java runtime cannot find scala standard library

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I had a simple sbt project and I ran `sbt package` to generate a jar file. However, it seems my java runtime cannot find the default scala library. May I know how I can fix this issue ?

FYI, if I run with `scala client_2.12-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` everything works fine.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) or [sbt-pack](https://github.com/xerial/sbt-pack) to create the complete package including dependencies. See their readmes and [What are key differences between sbt-pack and sbt-assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22556499/what-are-key-differences-between-sbt-pack-and-sbt-assembly).

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify Scala Library jar and other dependency jars when you run the sbt built jar with java

you can refer below link for more details

https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-run-scala-sbt-packaged-jar-file-with-java-command